# Cube map not working (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, reflection, glsl

I am trying to use OpenGL's cube mapping, but for some reason the y images are inverted and are screwing up the result, and the reflection, and refraction that am performing is not working properly.

Here's my code.

```
void initCubeMap()
{
    GLbyte *pBytes;
    GLint eFormat, iComponents;
    GLint width, height;

    // Cull backs of polygons
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);

    // Set up texture maps        
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); 

    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

    // Load Cube Map images
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {        
        // Load this texture map
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
        pBytes = utilities.loadTGA(cubeFaces[i], &width, &height, &iComponents, &eFormat);
        glTexImage2D(cube[i], 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
        free(pBytes);
    }

    glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP);
    glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP);
    glTexGeni(GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP);

    // Enable cube mapping, and set texture environment to decal
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
}

void renderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
        camera.RenderCam();
        camera.MoveCamMouse();

        // Sky Box is manually textured
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R); 

        drawSkyBox();

        // Use texgen to apply cube map
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);

        glPushMatrix();
            glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
            glPushMatrix();
                GLfloat m[16];
                glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
                camera.getCameraInverse(m);
                glMultMatrixf(m);
                glUseProgram(glassProgram);
                utilities.setUniform("Cubemap", 0);
                glutSolidSphere(5.0, 100, 100);
                glUseProgram(0);
            glPopMatrix();
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();

    // FPS
    frame++;

    time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    if (time - timebase > 1000) 
    {
        sprintf(s,"Template | FPS: %4.2f",frame*1000.0/(time-timebase));
        timebase = time;
        frame = 0;
    }

    glutSetWindowTitle((const char*)&s);

    // Swap double buffer for flicker-free animation
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void Camera::getCameraInverse(GLfloat *result)
{
    GLfloat resultTemp[16];
    float tmp[12];                                              //temporary pair storage
    float det;                                                  //determinant

    //calculate pairs for first 8 elements (cofactors)
    tmp[0] = result[10] * result[15];
    tmp[1] = result[11] * result[14];
    tmp[2] = result[9] * result[15];
    tmp[3] = result[11] * result[13];
    tmp[4] = result[9] * result[14];
    tmp[5] = result[10] * result[13];
    tmp[6] = result[8] * result[15];
    tmp[7] = result[11] * result[12];
    tmp[8] = result[8] * result[14];
    tmp[9] = result[10] * result[12];
    tmp[10] = result[8] * result[13];
    tmp[11] = result[9] * result[12];

    //calculate first 8 elements (cofactors)
    resultTemp[0] = tmp[0]*result[5] + tmp[3]*result[6] + tmp[4]*result[7] -    tmp[1]*result[5] - tmp[2]*result[6] - tmp[5]*result[7];

    resultTemp[1] = tmp[1]*result[4] + tmp[6]*result[6] + tmp[9]*result[7] -    tmp[0]*result[4] - tmp[7]*result[6] - tmp[8]*result[7];

    resultTemp[2] = tmp[2]*result[4] + tmp[7]*result[5] + tmp[10]*result[7] - tmp[3]*result[4] - tmp[6]*result[5] - tmp[11]*result[7];

    resultTemp[3] = tmp[5]*result[4] + tmp[8]*result[5] + tmp[11]*result[6] - tmp[4]*result[4] - tmp[9]*result[5] - tmp[10]*result[6];

    resultTemp[4] = tmp[1]*result[1] + tmp[2]*result[2] + tmp[5]*result[3] -    tmp[0]*result[1] - tmp[3]*result[2] - tmp[4]*result[3];

    resultTemp[5] = tmp[0]*result[0] + tmp[7]*result[2] + tmp[8]*result[3] -    tmp[1]*result[0] - tmp[6]*result[2] - tmp[9]*result[3];

    resultTemp[6] = tmp[3]*result[0] + tmp[6]*result[1] + tmp[11]*result[3] - tmp[2]*result[0] - tmp[7]*result[1] - tmp[10]*result[3];

    resultTemp[7] = tmp[4]*result[0] + tmp[9]*result[1] + tmp[10]*result[2] - tmp[5]*result[0] - tmp[8]*result[1] - tmp[11]*result[2];

    //calculate pairs for second 8 elements (cofactors)
    tmp[0] = result[2]*result[7];
    tmp[1] = result[3]*result[6];
    tmp[2] = result[1]*result[7];
    tmp[3] = result[3]*result[5];
    tmp[4] = result[1]*result[6];
    tmp[5] = result[2]*result[5];
    tmp[6] = result[0]*result[7];
    tmp[7] = result[3]*result[4];
    tmp[8] = result[0]*result[6];
    tmp[9] = result[2]*result[4];
    tmp[10] = result[0]*result[5];
    tmp[11] = result[1]*result[4];

    //calculate second 8 elements (cofactors)
    resultTemp[8] = tmp[0]*result[13] + tmp[3]*result[14] + tmp[4]*result[15] - tmp[1]*result[13] - tmp[2]*result[14] - tmp[5]*result[15];

    resultTemp[9] = tmp[1]*result[12] + tmp[6]*result[14] + tmp[9]*result[15] - tmp[0]*result[12] - tmp[7]*result[14] - tmp[8]*result[15];

    resultTemp[10] = tmp[2]*result[12] + tmp[7]*result[13] + tmp[10]*result[15] - tmp[3]*result[12] - tmp[6]*result[13] - tmp[11]*result[15];

    resultTemp[11] = tmp[5]*result[12] + tmp[8]*result[13] + tmp[11]*result[14] - tmp[4]*result[12] - tmp[9]*result[13] - tmp[10]*result[14];

    resultTemp[12] = tmp[2]*result[10] + tmp[5]*result[11] + tmp[1]*result[9] - tmp[4]*result[11] - tmp[0]*result[9] - tmp[3]*result[10];

    resultTemp[13] = tmp[8]*result[11] + tmp[0]*result[8] + tmp[7]*result[10] - tmp[6]*result[10] - tmp[9]*result[11] - tmp[1]*result[8];

    resultTemp[14] = tmp[6]*result[9] + tmp[11]*result[11] + tmp[3]*result[8] - tmp[10]*result[11] - tmp[2]*result[8] - tmp[7]*result[9];

    resultTemp[15] = tmp[10]*result[10] + tmp[4]*result[8] + tmp[9]*result[9] - tmp[8]*result[9] - tmp[11]*result[10] - tmp[5]*result[8];

    // calculate determinant
    det = result[0]*resultTemp[0] + result[1]*resultTemp[1] + result[2]*resultTemp[2] + result[3]*resultTemp[3];

    resultTemp[0] = resultTemp[0]/det;
    resultTemp[1] = resultTemp[1]/det;
    resultTemp[2] = resultTemp[2]/det;
    resultTemp[3] = resultTemp[3]/det;
    resultTemp[4] = resultTemp[4]/det;
    resultTemp[5] = resultTemp[5]/det;
    resultTemp[6] = resultTemp[6]/det;
    resultTemp[7] = resultTemp[7]/det;
    resultTemp[8] = resultTemp[8]/det;
    resultTemp[9] = resultTemp[9]/det;
    resultTemp[10] = resultTemp[10]/det;
    resultTemp[11] = resultTemp[11]/det;
    resultTemp[12] = resultTemp[12]/det;
    resultTemp[13] = resultTemp[13]/det;
    resultTemp[14] = resultTemp[14]/det;
    resultTemp[15] = resultTemp[15]/det;

    if(det==0.0f)
    {
        result[0] = 1.0;
        result[1] = 0.0;
        result[2] = 0.0;
        result[3] = 0.0;
        result[4] = 0.0;
        result[5] = 1.0;
        result[6] = 0.0;
        result[7] = 0.0;
        result[8] = 0.0;
        result[9] = 0.0;
        result[10] = 1.0;
        result[11] = 0.0;
        result[12] = 0.0;
        result[13] = 0.0;
        result[14] = 0.0;
        result[15] = 1.0;
    }

    result[0] = resultTemp[0];
    result[1] = resultTemp[4];
    result[2] = resultTemp[8];
    result[3] = resultTemp[12];
    result[4] = resultTemp[1];
    result[5] = resultTemp[5];
    result[6] = resultTemp[9];
    result[7] = resultTemp[13];
    result[8] = resultTemp[2];
    result[9] = resultTemp[6];
    result[10] = resultTemp[10];
    result[11] = resultTemp[14];
    result[12] = resultTemp[3];
    result[13] = resultTemp[7];
    result[14] = resultTemp[11];
    result[15] = resultTemp[15];
}
```

---

This is my OpenGL display function now. It still isn't working properly.

```
void renderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

        camera.RenderCam();
        camera.MoveCamMouse();

        // Sky Box is manually textured
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R); 

        drawSkyBox();

        // Use texgen to apply cube map
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);

        glUseProgram(glassProgram);
        utilities.setUniform("Cubemap", 0);
        glPushMatrix();
            glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glScalef(-1, -1, -1);
            glPushMatrix();
                GLfloat m[16];
                glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
                camera.getCameraInverse(m);
                glMultMatrixf(m);
                glutSolidSphere(5.0, 100, 100);
            glPopMatrix();
            glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPopMatrix();
        glUseProgram(0);

    glPopMatrix();
    // FPS
    frame++;

    time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    if (time - timebase > 1000) 
    {
        sprintf(s,"Texture Mapping | FPS: %4.2f",frame*1000.0/(time-timebase));
        timebase = time;
        frame = 0;
    }

    glutSetWindowTitle((const char*)&s);

    // Swap double buffer for flicker-free animation
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Here is my GLSL code to perform the reflection and refraction. Am not sure if there is something wrong here

```
// Vertex Shader

const float EtaR = 0.65;
const float EtaG = 0.67;         // Ratio of indices of refraction
const float EtaB = 0.69;
const float FresnelPower = 1.0;

const float F  = ((1.0-EtaG) * (1.0-EtaG)) / ((1.0+EtaG) * (1.0+EtaG));

varying vec3  Reflect;
varying vec3  RefractR;
varying vec3  RefractG;
varying vec3  RefractB;
varying float Ratio;

void main()
{
    vec4 ecPosition  = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    vec3 ecPosition3 = ecPosition.xyz / ecPosition.w;

    vec3 i = normalize(ecPosition3);
    vec3 n = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

    Ratio   = F + (1.0 - F) * pow((1.0 - dot(-i, n)), FresnelPower);

    RefractR = refract(i, n, EtaR);
    RefractR = vec3(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(RefractR, 1.0));
    RefractG = refract(i, n, EtaG);
    RefractG = vec3(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(RefractG, 1.0));

    RefractB = refract(i, n, EtaB);
    RefractB = vec3(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(RefractB, 1.0));

    Reflect  = reflect(i, n);
    Reflect  = vec3(gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(Reflect, 1.0));

    gl_Position = ftransform();
}

// Fragment Shader

varying vec3  Reflect;
varying vec3  RefractR;
varying vec3  RefractG;
varying vec3  RefractB;
varying float Ratio;

uniform samplerCube Cubemap;

void main()
{
    vec3 refractColor, reflectColor;

    refractColor.r = vec3(textureCube(Cubemap, RefractR)).r;
    refractColor.g = vec3(textureCube(Cubemap, RefractG)).g;
    refractColor.b = vec3(textureCube(Cubemap, RefractB)).b;

    reflectColor   = vec3(textureCube(Cubemap, Reflect));

    vec3 color     = mix(refractColor, reflectColor, Ratio);

    gl_FragColor   = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> but for some reason the y images are inverted and are screwing up the result

Yes, this is a rather common problem a lot of people experience. The reason for this is, that OpenGL cube maps follow the RenderMan specification, in which the scanline ordering is opposite to regular textures. This inconsistency is, well, inconsistent. When loading images from a file it's best addressed by inverting scanline ordering when loading the image. When doing a render to cube map texture one should flip the projection in the Y axis.

In your case an easy fix is to scale the texture matrix by -1 in the y, i.e.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glScale(1, -1, 1);
```

<s>and by swapping GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y and GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y images.</s>

Comment: There is still something wrong with it. By doing what you said, the images were in the right place, but they were getting mapped on to the model in reverse and the images are also not in the right orientation.

Comment: @Andre: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/358zxic/6

http://tinypic.com/r/sziz2w/6

Comment: @Andre: Please try out if you do *not* swap POSITIVE_Y with NEGATIVE_Y – honestly it's been quite some time I did code this from scratch and I might have got this one wrong. As for the model, please apply a `glScale(-1, -1, -1);` to the texture matrix when you apply it to the model as reflection. Oh, and just as general advice: For cube maps you should use GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE texture wrap mode.

Comment: That worked, but now the y images are in the right place, but they look like they have been rotated by 180 degrees, I don't know how. I haven't done anything to make that so. And can you tell me the reasoning behind using glScalef(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0) to solve the problem.

Comment: @Andre: The reasoning behind that glScale(-1,-1,-1) was to bring the cubemap into the right orientation. If the y images are looking "rotated", are they rotated or just mirrored? If so, you could add a glScale(1,1,-1); and swap POSITIVE_Z and NEGATIVE_Z images. This whole scaling and swapping mess is to compensate for that different scaline ordering of cubemap images. And keep in mind that you can contract all those different glScale into a single one, by componentwise multiplication.

Comment: I understand that these are hacks to force the program to work. I would like to know what the proper procedure is, and how I am deviating away from it to get an erroneous results.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried scaling, rotating, switching images. i have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Andre: I'm currently writing a tutorial using cubemaps anyway (only that it makes use of shaders). I'll add a fixed function branch and clear those issues up there as well.

Comment: Thanks alot. Please send me the link of your tutorial. Really appreciate it. Need to get this done asap. Thank you